# How SwiftUI onChange modifier works?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

I populated a SwiftUI Picker dynamically. The Picker is working successfully. I want to trigger or listen picker changing event. Suppose I will print the value if an user select an item. My iOS deployment target is 14, I found that iOS has an inbuilt function **onChange** to detect this kind of listener. I used that modifier but not working.
Here is my code:

```
var body: some View {
    
    
    
    Picker( selection: $selectedStrength, label: Text("Status")) {
        
        ForEach(courseList, id: \.self) { item in
            
            Text(item.courseCode ?? "")
        }
    }
    .onChange(of:selectedStrength, perform: { _ in
        
        print("Value Changed!")
        
    })
    .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that print("Value Changed!") is not called on selecting any item?

Comment: Yes, print("Value Changed!")  not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summery: I called a REST API and parse the data, then I tried to create a SwiftUI Picker from those data.

Solution: After searching a lot, I found the right solution. I was populating the Picker directly from Json object data. I converted those data into SwiftUI string array and tried **onChange** function, its working now.

My Code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct TeacherCourseListParser: Decodable, Hashable{
    
    var totalStudent: Int?
    var courseName: String?
    var courseCode: String?
    var courseId: Int?
    var courseTeacherEnrollId: Int?
    
    
}


    

struct Test: View {
    
    @State var courseList = [TeacherCourseListParser]()
          
    @State private var selectedStrength = ""
    @State var courseCodeTempArray = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            
            
            Picker( selection: $selectedStrength, label: Text("Course Code")) {
                
                ForEach(courseCodeTempArray, id: \.self) {
                    
                   
                    Text($0)
                    
                    
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedStrength, perform: { _ in
                
                print("Value Changed!")
            })
            .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            
            
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
```

Here is the function how I fetched the JSON object :

```
func FetchTeacherCourseCode(){
        
        
        
        
        let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "login_token")
      
        
        // create post request
                                                      
        guard let url = URL(string: Constant.mainServerUrl+Constant.getTeacherCourseList) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        print(url)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        // request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer "+token!
        ]
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                                                                                        
                    //-- Parse response according to the object
                    let detailedObjectFetcher = try! JSONDecoder().decode([TeacherCourseListParser].self, from: data)
                   
                    
                                                                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        for i in detailedObjectFetcher {
                            
                            // instead of populating Picker from JSON object directly I generated a string array                                                     
                            courseCodeTempArray.append(i.courseCode ?? "")
                            
                        }
                        
                       self.courseList = detailedObjectFetcher
                        showProgressBar = false
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    
                } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
                    Swift.print("could not find key \(key) in JSON: \(context.debugDescription)")
                } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let type, let context) {
                    Swift.print("could not find type \(type) in JSON: \(context.debugDescription)")
                } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) {
                    Swift.print("type mismatch for type \(type) in JSON: \(context.debugDescription)")
                } catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
                    Swift.print("data found to be corrupted in JSON: \(context.debugDescription)")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    NSLog("Error in read(from:ofType:) domain= \(error.domain), description= \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
            // print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            
        }.resume()
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it is due to type mismatch, Picker selection type and item type or (!) tag should be the same. As soon as you iterate by items but shows `courseCode` that is probably the reason of bug.

Try something like (not tested as provided code is not standalone and not runnable)

```
Picker(selection: $selectedStrength, label: Text("Status")) {
    
    ForEach(courseList, id: \.self) { item in
        
       // assiming selectedStrength type and item.courseCode type is the same
        Text(item.courseCode ?? "").tag(item.courseCode)
    }
}
.onChange(of: selectedStrength, perform: { _ in
    
    print("Value Changed!")
    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for implementation:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Tartan"]
        @State private var selectedColor = "Red"
    
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Picker("Please choose a color", selection: $selectedColor) {
                    ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                Text("You selected: \(selectedColor)")
            }
      

  }
}
```